# Retrieve functions (name, return type, parameters) from unknown dll (c++)

Tags: c++, dll

I need to work with a .dll (c++ 64bit) which is made by one of my company's vendors, and they no longer exist. I don't have the header file (.h).

I follow this:

[Get the function prototypes from an unknown .dll](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/)

I was able to get the function name, but I don't know what the function return type and parameters are.

I tried dependency walker too, same result.

This dll is not a public dll, it is customized for our company to use, so the functions inside cannot be searched online.

Are there any tools or methods that can help me retrieve this info?

Comment: Hello, I have search on those similar question on website before I ask this question here, but none of them can help me. I need to know solution urgent, please don't simply down vote.

Comment: There is no solution to your issue.... You could show your managers the answers you've got here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to work with a .dll (c++ 64bit) which is made by one of my company's vendors, and they no longer exist. I don't have the header file (.h).

In a professional setting, that is a symptom to **give up immediately using that library**, and find and use something else. Yes, that costs money and time (so advise your manager and/or client). You might prefer using some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) library instead next time (because [then](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) you could at least continue maintaining that library, even if its vendor disappeared).

You could consider that C++ usually do [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and try to [reverse-engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) something (but you won't be able to guess the fields inside `class`-es reliably or other information related to types). I don't recommend trying, since that could take a lot of time & money and you won't be able to guess everything (so you don't know if you'll guess enough information to use that stuff).

<sup>(what happens to you is a project mismanagement mistake, not a developer's mistake)</sup>

Using (even a few minutes) as a developer a C++ library without full headers and documentation for it is just *crazy*. **Don't do that**.

<sup>So there is no technical solution to your issue. [Decompilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) is generally impossible (and costs a big lot and usually don't work well)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it is a legacy product, ha, I am planning to give up the dll too, just want to test my luck here.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency walker should work for you. Here is an overview of how the functions, return types and arguments are displayed:

[dependency walker overview]  https://kb.froglogic.com/download/attachments/2457645/dependency_walker_provided_information.png?version=1&modificationDate=1341338967000

Remember that you have to use a different version of dependency walker for 32bit or 64bit dll. 
What is more, if you see some strange symbols in your function parameters like @,# etc..., then you are missing some dependent dll.

Comment: Hi, dependency walker just display function name only for my case.

Comment: From my experience you will need the header file so that you could also use enumerations, types etc, defined in the header file.